# How can bonuses or advantage be attained for attempts to gain control over a creature?

Tags: dnd-5e

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80080/how-to-debuff-will-or-wisdom-as-a-wizard) about Pathfinder has gotten me wondering about how willpower  might be more easily overcome in D&D 5e.

By gain control, I mean using a spell or ability to get a creature to "switch sides" and become an ally for a period of time.

It's OK if methods assume the target is captured.

Comment: Question is overly broad, and of the vein "List all the ways X could be done." Recommend providing additional information to narrow the scope of possible answers. Reference comments here: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79805/forcing-a-disadvantage-on-an-enemys-saving-throw/79806#79806

Comment: @Drunk Cynic I removed some of the broadening language, but I have to admit I'm scratching my head a bit, since the question is based on the one positively-rated one about Pathfinder. I didn't want to just copy and paste the other poster's question and change the tag. Does the edit address your concern?

Comment: Your linked Question is narrowed to Pathfinder Wizards, with a specific goal of supporting Charm and Dominate Spells. My linked Question is similarly up voted, but was closed due to being overly broad. Even with the edits applied, this Question is much closer to the my example than yours. At current, a answer to this question would be a listing of every effect in 5e that would strengthen attempts to gain control over a target creature. This would be an encyclopedic reading of the resources.

Comment: OK, so I narrowed it down to charm and dominate. But the Pathfinder question is from the point of view of a character wanting to optimize his character. Mine is from a DM looking to create villains, so the class is irrelevant. 

What I don't get is, as I edit the question, it's sounding more and more like "Read the wizard class description to me" (which I don't need) rather than something that could have creative combination of effects I hadn't thought ot. Maybe I should just delete it?

Comment: Including the point of view you just stated, trying to create villains, would be a strong start towards narrowing this question.

Comment: [This](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79805/forcing-a-disadvantage-on-an-enemys-saving-throw?lq=1#comment179829_79805) comment applies equally here - this is looking for a list of every effect that gives disadvantage to a saving throw, and there are a lot of those.

Comment: Really, I never asked for a list, but point taken. My question is probably a better fit for a forum where you can have more open ended exchange of ideas, etc. Go ahead and close. I would delete it if it didn't ask me not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorcerer's metamagic:

> Heightened Spell
>
> When you cast a spell that forces a creature to make a
> saving throw to resist its effects, you can spend 3 sorcery
> points to give one target of the spell disadvantage on its
> first saving throw made against the spell.

Wizard's school of divination:

> Portent
>
> Starting at 2nd level when you choose this school,
> glimpses o f the future begin to press in on your awareness. When you
> finish a long rest, roll two d20s and record the numbers rolled. You
> can replace any attack roll, saving throw, or ability check made by
> you or a creature that you can see with one o f these foretelling
> rolls. You must choose to do so before the roll, and you can replace a
> roll in this way only once per turn. Each foretelling roll can be used
> only once. When you finish a long rest, you lose any unused
> foretelling rolls.

Rogue's Arcane Trickster:

> Magical Ambush
>
> Starting at 9th level, if you are hidden
> from a creature when you cast a spell on it, the creature has
> disadvantage on any saving throw it makes against the spell this turn.